# Why chrome.downloads.download doesn't work without adding another function following it.(it worked when add alert() after it)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that using the `chrome.downloads.download` API. My extension is to capture a download event and trigger `webkitNotification`. I post the major working function of my modification from one of google's samples.

```
function downloadCheckedLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
        if (document.getElementById('check' + i).checked) {         
            chrome.downloads.download({url: visibleLinks[i]}, function(id) {
                var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('',
                               'OMG', 'hello within for loop, succeed!');
                notification.show();
            });
            alert("function executed!");
        }
    }
    window.close();
}
```

The problem is when I remove the `alert("function executed")`, it only worked in the debug mode, in which I set a breakpoint in the for loop and step through the code. In the normal mode, I have to add something to make it work (i.e. `alert()`). I feel like it is because the asynchronous function call of `chrome.downloads.download()`.

Since I am new to the web development word, I don't exactly know where my problem is. Could any one help me figure out what happened here? If possible, could you please teach me that in a asynchronous function call like this `chrome.downloads.download()`, when the anonymous callback function is called exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Comment `window.close()` can work. I guess when the window is closed, the download call is canceled. But I can't give the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is executed in the context of the document. If you issue a window.close your javascript function is stopped and it's code and data garbage collected. 
chrome.downloads.download is probably async because of the callback function. 
Javascript engines are single threaded. For this reason as long as your for loop is executing no other javascript is running. The calls to chrome.downloads.download are queued to some internal javascript engine queue: to be executed as soon as the current function is ended.
The last statement you issue is window.close();

The javascript queue still holds some functions to be executed but window.close() wins: the queue is killed, your callbacks never get fired.

It works when you use a debugger: the debugger keeps your window referenced and therfore in memory, which enabled the javascript engine to execute the queued functions.

If you add a couple of lines to your code you can close the window if all downloads have ended:

```
function downloadCheckedLinks() {
    var pending = 0; // closure var
    for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
        if (document.getElementById('check' + i).checked) {
            pending = pending + 1;       
            chrome.downloads.download({url: visibleLinks[i]}, function(id) {
                var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('',
                               'OMG', 'hello within for loop, succeed!');
                notification.show();
                pending = pending - 1;
                if (pending <1) {
                   window.close();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```